# How to hide a text in a footer

Tags: html, css

i have the following as part of a .CSS file:-

```
    #footer-profile {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: blue;
    background: yellow;
    opacity: .3;
    -moz-opacity: .3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #999999;
}
```

but how can i hide the text within the footer

Comment: Can you post your markup, please?

Comment: Agree that some markup would be good to see. However, could you wrap the text within a <p> tag and set that as display:hidden?

Comment: @test test  #footer{font-size:0;} and now your footer text is remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add inside `#footer` directive

`display: none;`

the whole footer will be hidden. If you want to hide only some part of the footer, add them inside some tag with class `hidden` and then add a rule:

```
#footer.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you could try to use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`. The first one will hide the element but will keep free its space in the layout, the second one will 'collapse' the element and may change your layout.

For completeness sake, I would like to add the solution provided by Rohit Azar as a comment to your post:

```
#footer {
   font-size: 0;
}
```

This solution does exactly what the question asks.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide only the text, try this:

```
#footer{
text-indent:-99999px;
}
```